# Angular Material Dialog: How to update data in table row when they change after afterClosed?

Tags: angular, angular-material

After close modal dialog in table not updtae row.
In `this.usersData` row is updated, but in table not updated.
How i can update row?

```
usersData: MatTableDataSource<any>;

listUsers() {
    this.usersService.usersList(limit, page, param)
      .subscribe((res) => {
          this.usersData = new MatTableDataSource(res.rows);
        },
        (err) => {
          console.log('listUsers_err', err);
        }
      );
}

editUser(id, i) {
    const dialogConfig = {
      disableClose: true,
      autoFocus: false,
      data: {
        userId: id
      }
    };

    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(UserEditComponent, dialogConfig);

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      this.usersData.data[i] = result;    // <--- not updated in table aftrer close modal
    });
  }
```

`"@angular/material": "^11.0.3",`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a data array is provided, the table must be notified when the array's objects are added, removed, or moved. This can be done by calling the `renderRows()` function which will render the diff since the last table render. If the data array reference is changed, the table will automatically trigger an update to the rows, [table api...](https://material.angular.io/components/table/api)

```
export class Component {
  @ViewChild(MatTable) table: MatTable<any>;

  ...
  editUser(id, i) {
    ...
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      this.usersData.data[i] = result; // <--- not updated in table aftrer close modal
      this.table.renderRows();
    });
  }
}
```